# Powershell Output to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, powershell, google-sheets

I have one Powershell script which will create Csv file in my desktop,
Rather I need to directly put output to Google Sheets.

When I run the script in Google Sheets, It need to get the data from Powershell and paste it in Google Sheets.

I searched for the best result in Internet, But i am not getting solution
Thanks

Comment: You can try using the Google Sheets API - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts. A warning beforehand - it's a lot more complicated than it looks.

Comment: About `When I run the script in Google Sheets, It need to get the data from Powershell and paste it in Google Sheets.`, I think that in order to directly run the Powershell script on the local PC using Google Apps Script, it is required to set the server in the local PC. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this is the goal you expect. In this case, for example, when the CSV data is uploaded from the local PC to Google Spreadsheet using Powershell, and the CSV data is put to the Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script, the script might become simpler. Is this direction included in your goal?